# Longest Incresing Subsequence to solve building bridge

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, lis

I've something that bothers me. I'm trying to solve building bridge problem which have this information as a instruction.

> Building Bridges
>   Consider a 2-D map with a horizontal river passing through its center. There are n cities on the southern bank with x-coordinates a(1) ... a(n) and n cities on the northern bank with x-coordinates b(1) ... b(n).
>   You want to connect as many north-south pairs of cities as possible with bridges such that no two bridges cross. When connecting cities, you can only connect city i on the northern bank to city i on the southern bank."

I did research on Stack Overflow and found out some topic that really help me a lot such as:
[Building bridges problem - how to apply longest increasing subsequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288585/building-bridges-problem-how-to-apply-longest-increasing-subsequence) 
and
[How to determine the longest increasing subsequence using dynamic programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631726/how-to-determine-the-longest-increasing-subsequence-using-dynamic-programming)

But when I come up with LIS and trying to solve one sample list by hand. Let's say I have

```
Northern Bank >> 7 4 3 6 2 1 5
Southern Bank >> 5 3 2 4 6 1 7
```

After sort southern bank

```
Northern Bank >> 1 3 4 6 7 2 5 
Southern Bank >> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Which LIS length suppose to be "5" but actually in the first list, Only 3 bridge are able to create (3,2,1). So did I misunderstand LIS or are there any exception on this that won't work on building bridge problem?

Comment: You've probably confused x coordinates with order indices.  Try an example with x coordinates 10, 20, ...70 and it might be more obvious.

Comment: thank you jwpat7. I did confused for real. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that you have correctly solved the problem using the longest increasing subsequence:

[image]

You can build all 5 black bridges (but not the 2 red ones).

Why do you think you can only make 3 bridges?

Comment: the instruction said that you can only connect city i on the northern bank to city i on the southern bank." So I though that we've to connect to the same number on both side. Am I misunderstand the instruction cause if not, when I recheck back to original sequence

Northern Bank >> 7 4 3 6 2 1 5
Southern Bank >> 5 3 2 4 6 1 7

I can connect only 3, 2,1 or 3,6,1 or 4,6,1 only

Comment: The original sequence is saying that north city 1 at x 7.0 can only connect to south city 1 at x 5.0, north city 2 at a 4.0 can only connect to south city 2 at x 3.0, etc.  In other words, the original sequence specifies the locations of 7 possible bridges - the ones shown in my diagram.  Note the numbers in my diagram are x positions.  The city indices are not shown.

Comment: thank you Peter de Rivaz. I got it now. Your answer really help me a lot.